# Get USB Device Name In UBUNTU

Tags: command-line, usb, mount

I'm looking for a command for UBUNTU that I can throw into Terminal to give me some USB device name given its mounted location in UBUNTU. For instance, I have an Arduino Leonardo board attached to my UBUNTU computer via USB. If I use ls /dev/tty.*, I see that I have a device mounted to /dev/tty.usbmodem1411. I know that this device is the Arduino Leonardo, but I do not know the command to confirm this from the Terminal in UBUNTU.

Here some requirements for this question...

1) This must work on UBUNTU.

2) I'd prefer not to download/install any other scripts/etc off the net.

3) I'd prefer a method that does not include `sed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `lsusb`. It will return information as to what is connected to your computer and on what bus.

However, it does not (and can not) look at the connected TTYs, as this would require opening a session with the TTY and a few other things.